# Multiple file upload `reader.onloadend` is not firing

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload, primeng, zonejs

I'm using `p-fileUpload` in `Angular 6.0.0` app, for uploading the image files (In this case multiple images files). It has an event handler `(uploadHandler)` for the **uploaded** files.

```
<p-fileUpload multiple="true" name="myfile[]" accept="image/*" [auto]="true" 
      customUpload="true" chooseLabel="Select" (uploadHandler)="uploadImage($event)">
 </p-fileUpload>
```

The files are getting uploaded correctly, but I'm not able to generate the base64   code when looping over the `e.files` array, because `reader.onloadend` is not firing. I've searched this firing issue and found some related questions but the solution of them is not solving my problem. Below is the code I've written for multiple image file upload -

```
uploadImage(e: any) {
if (e && e.files.length) {
  const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  e.files.forEach((i: File, j: any) => {
    reader.onloadend = (ev: any) => {
      console.log('inside??');
      // Console is not triggered
    };
    // reader.readAsDataURL(...);
    this.cdr.markForCheck(); // For outside zone detection
  });
}
```

}

**Please help me with this problem**.
I'm using this same code for single image upload (so I don't need `forEach` loop there) inside the same app and it is working in all other places unlike in this case.

Comment: The onloadend event cannot trigger if the corresponding .readAsDataURL call does not work